# Seeing shell commands as they are being executed including variables

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I can do

```
bash -x mysellh.sh
```

to see the commands as they are being executed, but I don't see the variables replaced with their values. For instance, if I have in the shell script:

```
screen -d -m sh -c 'RAILS_ENV="$R_ENV" bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex[500] > "$PROJECT_DIR"/solr/indexing_out.txt'
```

I will see:

```
+ screen -d -m sh -c 'RAILS_ENV="$R_ENV" bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex[500] > "$PROJECT_DIR"/solr/indexing_out.txt'
```

Even though I've already declared earlier:

```
R_ENV=test
```

Is there an option to do what I want?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is doing what you asked: the command line "word" that `$R_ENV` is in is what you have enclosed in single quotes, which inhibit expansion.  The -x output is showing you the non-expansion.  If you want those variables to be expanded, enclose that first "word" in double quotes and use single quotes in the contents, like this:

```
screen -d -m sh -c "RAILS_ENV='$R_ENV' bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex[500] > '$PROJECT_DIR'/solr/indexing_out.txt"
```

Then the single quotes are around the expanded text and the double quotes allow the variables to expand.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am trying to be a bit more efficient in shell programming